# potential risks in upgrading AKS 1.21 to 1.25

Tags: azure, upgrade, azure-aks

we want to upgrade AKS from 1.21 to 1.25 as 1.25 is the supported version in AKS right now and AKS does not allow version to upgraded like EKS one minor version at a time.

what are the potential risks?

We have made sure all the deprecated APIs are not used anymore. other than what can be the risks with this big version jump.

The upgrade will be done in the 1.21 cluster not creating a new one. Please let me know in your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experience

- After upgrading AKS 1.25.x, we faced High memory consumption issue.
- And later when we checked about that issue we got this [aks forum link](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/3443) where peoples are discussing about memory issue.
- In our case we have to upgrade our NodeJS application to 20.x to match the aks-1.25.x requirement.
- And for different applications their are different requirements so you can visit [Memory saturation occurs in pods after cluster upgrade to Kubernetes 1.25](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/aks-memory-saturation-after-upgrade#solution)
- As per my suggestion, first of all update your applications so they become compatible with aks 1.25.x

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the memory issue. you have saved me from a lot of headache. I see from the thread that using AKS Linux with legacy cgroup will solve the problem. We have many apps with different version so updating them all is impossible. Btw we are moving to 1.27

Answer (score 1):

Two recommendations:

1. Check all your [add-ons and extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/integrations) for breaking changes as well
2. Try out the upgrade in a staging environment first. If anything breaks after the upgrade, you can't downgrade the existing cluster anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As per [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/supported-kubernetes-versions?tabs=azure-cli) currently `1.21` is deprecated and the current version available in AKS is `1.25` so using that I am showing you the version upgrade from `1.25 to 1.27,` you can apply this same logic for `1.21 to 1.25`.

```
az aks get-upgrades --resource-group <RgName> --name <clusterName> --output table
```

[image]

By default, Kubernetes uses a ***semantic versioning*** i.e. **major** then **minor** then **patch** so with that logic `1.25.6 -> 1.25.11 -> 1.26.3 -> 1.27.1`In AKS, upgrading from 1.21 to 1.25 in a single jump is not recommended.

In my Aks environment I am upgrading  `1.25.6 -> 1.25.11`  like below:

[image]

[image]

Now, 1.25 to 1.26

[image]

[image]

Now 1.26.3 to 1.27.1:

[image]

Finally, you can verify the same using kubectl cmd:

```
 kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

[image]

This is the safe way to upgrade your Kubernetes version in AKS if you directly jump from 1.21 to 1,25, it may cause below issues-

- There may be breaking changes and compatibility issues could cause your applications to fail or could have performance regressions.